# Magento site crashes when going to the sales -> orders page

Tags: php, mysql, magento

My magento site crashes when I go to the sales -> orders page, even though I recently upgraded the server to 8 gigs of ram.  We have around 5-6k visitors per day, and around 6k products.  It runs faster and doesn't crash nearly as much as it did previously, but still crashes on the orders page.  I've run through every magento tutorial I could find but I'm still having trouble.  Here's my my.cnf to see if that could possibly be causing the error:

[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM

max_connections=400
key_buffer_size=256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
join_buffer_size=2M
read_buffer_size=1M
sort_buffer_size=1M
table_open_cache=2500
thread_cache_size=128
interactive_timeout=45
wait_timeout=20
connect_timeout=8
max_allowed_packet=16M
max_connect_errors=10
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=128M
query_cache_type=1
table_definition_cache = 512
max_heap_table_size = 64M
tmp_table_size = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4096M
tmpdir=/home/mysqltemp

[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit=8192

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size=64M
sort_buffer_size=64M
read_buffer_size=16M
write_buffer_size=16M

Am I looking in the right place, or should I be looking somewhere else to trace the problem?

Edit: To clarify, I get a 500 error in magento and the mysql server crashes.  
Mysqltemp is set to home, so there's no size limitations.

Comment: Define "crashes". Does Apache crash? Does the web server crash?

Comment: How big is the drive with /home/mysqltemp on it?

Comment: Both. I get a 500 server error, and mysql goes down.  I have mysqltemp to the home directory, so it's a huge drive.

Comment: Anything dumped into mysql-error.log?

Comment: Anything in the magento logs?

Comment: Of the 8 gigs of ram how much is being used when you go to TOP? How big is your database? Are your logs in the db huge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check both apache and mysql logs for more information

depending on your OS, check the log files and I may be able to help with further info:

```
/etc/httpd/logs/error.log

/var/logs/mysql/*.log
```

**One possible issue:**

Are you running a 32 bit OS, and a 32 Bit version of MySQL?
If so putting `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4096M` above about 2GIG will cause a crash as MySQL won't be stable.

I suggest putting `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M` and seeing if the server becomes stable.
For detailed information about `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, refer [Official MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)

Comment: I'm running a 64bit version of CentOS.

Comment: I set the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1024m and it definitely helped.  Thank you!

Comment: You are possibly using 32bit MySQL, you should look at mysql_x64